How XGBoost guarantees descend with a Newton step?
I am reading about XGBoost and I have found out that compared to Gradient Boosting, the step at each iteration is given by Newton's method instead of gradient descend.
However, Newton's method is not guaranteed to descend and may even ascend. How XGBoost guarantees that at each step we actually descend? The only thing that comes to my mind is that due to the nature (convex) of commonly used loss functions (e.g MSE), the iterate will descend.
The following excerpt seems to confirm my intuition but I am not sure. After equation 2 in the paper (page 2 of pdf), authors state:

Here $l$ is a differentiable convex loss function that measures the
difference between the prediction $\hat{y}_i$ and the target $y_i$.


You are correct, the basic point is that we work with a convex differentiable cost function indeed.
The other point is that by controlling the learning rate/shrinkage $\eta$ we can take reasonably small steps such that we don't oscillate/overshoot either. That way, the Newton step (or any other gradient method really) operates within a region where its assumptions about function behaviour are confirmed (See the concept of trust region in optimisation for more details on this.) As such, and to answer the main question of the title: There is no explicit guarantee "that at each step we actually descend" because given a large enough $\eta$ we can overshoot.
